# mint4win.exe doesn't works on Linux Mint 14 (32-bit) on Windows 7

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am a recent fan of Linux Mint MATE and I found that its a nice work. Recently I have been facing an issue with the mint4win.exe. The package as a whole works since I have driven the OS live using a flash drive. I wanted to install it alongwith Windows 7 but when I try to open mint4win.exe, it doesn't runs. Kindly help!

Comment: The installed windows is a Genuine 64-bit Home Premium copy.

Comment: Maybe try right-clicking and running the program as admin?

Comment: it doesn't, even I tried running it with a suffix --32bit!!

Comment: How would a suffix help? Maybe the file's corrupted. According to what I've read the included Mint4Win.exe file should work fine with Mint 14 "Nadia" in Win7.

Comment: i tried another copy of a 64 bit version of mint nadia.. that too doesn't work.. the suffix wouldhelp in a similar way it works for wubi.exe in Ubuntu. See the faqs for wubi.exe . Here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Can_I_force_Wubi_to_download_and_install_a_32_bit_version_of_Ubuntu.3F

Comment: Ah, by "suffix" you meant "command-line argument". I thought you added that string to the filename itself. Anyway, an arg like that will only work if it's supported by the EXE; you can't just use random args with any EXE.

Comment: I had to clear all the harddisk using diskpart since there were some previous wubi partitions on the drive. Thanks anyways! The mint4win.exe packaged in 32-bit image now works on 64-bit also!